# NHibernate join query throwing error

Tags: c#, nhibernate, join

I'm trying to implement a join query. I need to get the name of the column id

```
string hql = "select new TerminalStateReportItem(p.Ip, p.Error, p.Terminal_Id, p.Last_Activity, p.Current_Page, p.Ping, u.Name) from TerminalState p join User u on p.Terminal_Id=u.Id";
var query = new SimpleQuery<TerminalStateReportItem>(hql);
return query.Execute();
```

I receive an error

> Castle.ActiveRecord.Framework.ActiveRecordException: Could not perform ExecuteQuery for TerminalStateReportItem ---> NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.SemanticException: Path expected for join! [select new TerminalStateReportItem(p.Ip, p.Error, p.Terminal_Id, p.Last_Activity, p.Current_Page, p.Ping, u.Name) from KioskServer.TerminalState.TerminalState p join User1 u on p.Terminal_Id=u.Id]

My class wrapper

```
namespace KioskServer.Reports
{
    [ActiveRecord]
    public class TerminalStateReportItem
    {
        public TerminalStateReportItem()
        {
        }

        public TerminalStateReportItem(string ip, string error, int terminalId, DateTime lastActivity, string currentPage, int ping, string name)
        {
            Ip = ip;
            Error = error;
            Terminal_Id = terminalId;
            Last_Activity = lastActivity;
            Current_Page = currentPage;
            Ping = ping;
            Name = name;
        }

        [PrimaryKey]
        public string Ip { get; set; }
        public string Error { get; set; }
        public int Terminal_Id { get; set; }
        public DateTime Last_Activity { get; set; }
        public string Current_Page { get; set; }
        public int Ping { get; set; }
        public string Name{ get; set; }
    }
}
```

my class table

```
namespace KioskServer.TerminalState
{
    [ActiveRecord("terminal_state")]
    public class TerminalState
    {
        public TerminalState(){
        }

        public TerminalState(string ip, string error, int terminalId, DateTime lastActivity, string currentPage, int ping)
        {
            Ip = ip;
            Error = error;
            Terminal_Id = terminalId;
            Last_Activity = lastActivity;
            Current_Page = currentPage;
            Ping = ping;
        }

        [PrimaryKey]
        public string Ip { get; set; }
        [Property]
        public string Error { get; set; }
        [Property]
        public int Terminal_Id { get; set; }
        [Property]
        public DateTime Last_Activity { get; set; }
        [Property]
        public string Current_Page { get; set; }
        [Property]
        public int Ping { get; set; }
    }
}
```

without joining all works normally. maybe because my classes are in different folders?

```
namespace KioskServer.Data.Users
{
    [ActiveRecord("users",
        DiscriminatorColumn = "usertype",
        DiscriminatorType = "string",
        DiscriminatorValue = "user")]
    public class User : Entity
    {
        [Property]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Property]
        public string Login { get; set; }

        [Property]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        [Property]
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }

        [BelongsTo]
        public Dealer Dealer { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I do a query

```
string hql = "select new TerminalStateItem(p.Ip, p.Error, p.Terminal_Id, p.Last_Activity, p.Current_Page, p.Ping, u.Name) from TerminalState p join p.User u";
```

error

```
NHibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: User of: KioskServer.TerminalState.TerminalState [select new TerminalStateItem(p.Ip, p.Error, p.Terminal_Id, p.Last_Activity, p.Current_Page, p.Ping, u.Name) from KioskServer.TerminalState.TerminalState p join p.User u]
```

Answer (score 0):

The HQL is a language working over your Domain Model. It is not a SQL. What that means?

While in SQL you can say:

```
SELECT **
FROM  TerminalState p   -- (table TerminalState)
JOIN User1 u            -- (table User1)
ON p.Terminal_Id = u.Id -- (the relation
```

In HQL you cannot! Becuase the ON is defined by the relation... by the **path**. So the *Exception* here says:

> **Path expected for join!**

The domain relation, the path among objects, e.g. this will work in HQL:

```
select new p.Ip, u.Name ...
from TerminalState p 
// now the PATH
join p.User u  // not needed on p.Terminal_Id=u.Id";
```

The `ON` *(SQL syntax generated by NHibernate without our explicit defintion)*  must come from the mapping. there must be User property on TerminalState mapped as `many-to-one`...

See more here:

- [14. HQL: The Hibernate Query Language](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#queryhql)
- [14.3. Associations and joins](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#queryhql-joins)

In case, you need some special SQL, you still can get it with NHibernate, just use:

```
session.CreateSQLQuery() // could contain any valid SQL
```

instead of `session.CreateQuery()` *(expecting HQL)*

Comment: join p.User u not worcking
join User u   not worcking
I added the question. I still can not connect

Comment: But throwing different exception right? maybe you should update your question with that progress. also, check my links, to get more understanding about hql, because your select with new() is not hql, I'd say..

Comment: once again updated the question. I beg you, look again

Comment: And that's it, exactly as I explained in a part of my answer: `User` must be property of the `TerminalState `, in order to use it in HQL ... for JOIN. ANd this is not the case. You cannot use such a join with HQL. it is driven by the **Domain model**, not by SQL... does it help? Or am I still unclear? ... HQL is a query language on top of existing relations... it cannot be creating new ON relations... just these, which were mapped. Please, try to read the docs I gave you

Answer (score 0):

You should have a mapping
[Property]
public User User { get; set; }

in the class TerminalStateReportItem

Then you can query.